Pressure of column of air and pressure of cinder block - what makes the pressure to apply from below in the former and not in the latter?
Pressure is force per unit of area.
I understand that the pressure at the ground is the force the column of air (above a surface of one square meter) exerts on that surface of one square meter. To be more colloquial, it's the force "on the shoulders" of that one-square-meter surface.

Now let's put an umbrella on the ground. I can't distinguish the following two cases:


a pressure of $1$ atm is exerted by the air on top (and, weirdly, on the bottom as well) of the umbrella.
a pressure of $1$ atm is exerted by a cinder block on top (and only on top) of the umbrella. Note: in this second case, we imagine there is no air.

More precisely, I can't understand the reason why the air has the ability to exert a pressure from behind the umbrella, when in fact the air column is located on top of it.

Is it possible to answer this with a strict definition of pressure as a force per unit of surface ? I mean I've heard and understood that there were other definition of pressure, encompassing notions such as brownian motion. My second question, if this is right, is then: could we restrict ourselves to the notion of pressure as force per unit area to answer first question ?


I answered what I think is a similar question awhile ago about liquid.  The key is to consider that under static loading, the infinitessimal elements of liquid or air can only support compression, but not tension or shear.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/824179/if-pressure-is-caused-by-the-weight-of-water-above-you-why-is-pressure-said-to/824181#824181

Here is the difference you are missing.
Air cannot support shear forces when stress is applied to it. This means that the only contact force it can convey is hydrostatic pressure.
Cinder blocks can sustain shear forces (i.e., they are solid) and so they convey their weight through, in your example, compressive stress- which squashes anything underneath them.



a pressure of 1
atm is exerted by the air on top (and, weirdly, on the bottom as well) of the umbrella.
a pressure of 1
atm is exerted by a cinder block on top (and only on top) of the umbrella. Note: in this second case, we imagine there is no air.


In case 1, air is above and below the umbrella.
In case 2, cinder blocks are above the umbrella and a vacuum is below it.
So you are not really comparing "air" to "concrete." Rather, you are comparing "air/air" to "concrete/vacuum."
To make the situations more analogous, let's put cinder blocks not only on top of the umbrella, but also underneath it, similar to how some of the atmosphere is above the umbrella and the rest is underneath it. In this "concrete/concrete" situation, we will reach a similar result to the "air/air" situation, as follows:
Let's say there is a stack of $N_{top}$ cinder blocks on top of the umbrella, each with surface area $A$ and mass $m$. Then, below the umbrella, there is a stack of $N_{bottom}$ cinder blocks with the same area and mass. Assume the two stacks are aligned and that everything is at equilibrium (i.e. stationary, not buckling or squashing). The pressure on the umbrella is then
$$\frac{mgN_{top}}{A}.$$ You can calculate this using Newton's 3rd law -- the umbrella must exert a force of $mgN_{top}$ on the cinder block above it to prevent the top stack from accelerating downwards.
Note that $N_{bottom}$ does not affect the pressure at all. As in the air/air case, only the stuff on top of the umbrella matters.
Also, as in the air/air case, the pressure is exerted equally on both sides of the umbrella. The umbrella has no net force on it and does not move -- it is trapped between the cinder blocks. This means that there is an upward force on the bottom of the umbrella that is exactly the same as the downward force.
As you can see, the situations are actually quite similar in some ways, once you make them sufficiently analogous. Hopefully this shows, at least, that the presence of an upward force, proportional to the total weight of material above the umbrella, is not unique to air.


If we have a very ideal, very smooth ball, and the size of the ball is also the same, then in this U-shaped container, due to the downward force of gravity, the downward force on the red plane is the same as the upward force.
Coal blocks are irregular and have friction with each other, so coal blocks cannot achieve such an effect.
